# Swift3 Random Extension Method

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I was using this extension method to generate a random number:

```
func Rand(_ range: Range<UInt32>) -> Int {
        return Int(range.lowerBound + arc4random_uniform(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound + 1))
    }
```

I liked it b/c it was no nonsense, you just called it like this:

```
 let test = Rand(1...5) //generates a random number between 1 and 5
```

I honestly don't know why things need to be so complicated in Swift but I digress..

So i'm receiving an error now in Swift3

```
No '...' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Range<UInt32>'
```

Would anyone know what this means or how I could get my awesome Rand function working again? I guess x...y no longer creates Ranges or x..y must be explicitly defined as UInt32? Any advice for me to make things a tad easier?

Thanks so much, appreciate your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3 there are four Range structures:

- `"x" ..< "y"` ⇒ `Range<T>`
- `"x" ... "y"` ⇒ `ClosedRange<T>`
- `1 ..< 5` ⇒ `CountableRange<T>`
- `1 ... 5` ⇒ `CountableClosedRange<T>`

(The operators `..<` and `...` are overloaded so that if the elements are stridable (random-access iterators e.g. numbers and pointers), a Countable Range will be returned. But these operators can still return plain Ranges to satisfy the type checker.)

Since Range and ClosedRange are different structures, you cannot implicitly convert a them with each other, and thus the error.

If you want Rand to accept a ClosedRange as well as Range, you must overload it:

```
// accepts Rand(0 ..< 5)
func Rand(_ range: Range<UInt32>) -> Int {
    return Int(range.lowerBound + arc4random_uniform(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound))
}

// accepts Rand(1 ... 5)
func Rand(_ range: ClosedRange<UInt32>) -> Int {
    return Int(range.lowerBound + arc4random_uniform(range.upperBound + 1 - range.lowerBound))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A nice solution is presented in [Generic Range Algorithms](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/generic-range-algorithms/) 
(based on [How to be DRY on ranges and closed ranges?](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20161010/003654.html) in the swift-users mailing list).

It uses the fact that both `CountableRange` and `CountableClosedRange`
are *collections,* and in fact a `RandomAccessCollection`.

So you can define a single (generic) function which accepts both open and closed
integer ranges:

```
func rand<C: RandomAccessCollection>(_ coll: C) -> C.Iterator.Element {
    precondition(coll.count > 0, "Cannot select random element from empty collection")
    let offset = arc4random_uniform(numericCast(coll.count))
    let idx = coll.index(coll.startIndex, offsetBy: numericCast(offset))
    return coll[idx]
}

rand(1...5) // random number between 1 and 5
rand(2..<10) // random number between 2 and 9
```

but also:

```
rand(["a", "b", "c", "d"]) // random element from the array
```

Alternatively as a protocol extension method:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {

    func rand() -> Iterator.Element {
        precondition(count > 0, "Cannot select random element from empty collection")
        let offset = arc4random_uniform(numericCast(count))
        let idx = index(startIndex, offsetBy: numericCast(offset))
        return self[idx]
    }
}

(1...5).rand()
(2..<10).rand()
["a", "b", "c", "d"].rand()
```

Comment: Is there is way to limit your `rand` function to only accept a collection of `Int`?

Comment: @rmaddy: `func rand<C: RandomAccessCollection>(_ coll: C) -> C.Iterator.Element where C.Iterator.Element == Int` for the free function, or `extension RandomAccessCollection where Iterator.Element == Int` for the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite `Rand()` to use `Int` if that is your primary use case:

```
func Rand(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
    let distance = UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return range.lowerBound + Int(arc4random_uniform(distance + 1))
}
```

Or as kennytm points out, use `Rand(1..<6)`