# Ranges in Swift3

Tags: swift, range

I'm struggling with one of the Swift3 changes. Earlier they treated `...` and `..<` as `Range`, but now they have a ton of new "sub-ranges". I would like to have a function taking both range variants.

```
struct Test {
  var data = [1,2,3,4,5]
  subscript(r:Range<Int>) -> [Int] {
    return Array(data[r])
  }
}
let t = Test()
print(t[0...1]) // fails because now this is a ClosedRange
print(t[0..<2])
```

I'd like to have a

```
  subscript(r:TakesAnyRange<Int>) -> [Int] {
```

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40377303/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Exactly :-) I like it, when compiler designers replace a simple construct by one that needs at least a doctor's degree >:-|

Comment: @MartinR Now, since this is a simplified question, I found that for a `subscript` your solution does not work. Do you have another pointer?

Comment: I have re-opened the question and would suggest that you update it accordingly.

Comment: @MartinR Done. Now hoping for the best :-)

Comment: `subscript` cannot be generic. – You can define *two* subscript methods one for `Range<Int>` and one for `ClosedRange<Int>` (which is what was suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/40371418/1187415, and is also what `struct Array` does in the standard library).

Comment: @MartinR I wanted to avoid that duplication. Well, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the duplication by instead using `CountableRange` and `CountableClosedRange`, since one is convertible to the other:

```
struct Test {
  var data = [1,2,3,4,5]

  subscript(r: CountableRange<Int>) -> [Int] {
    return Array(data[r])
  }

  subscript(r: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> [Int] {
    return self[CountableRange(r)]
  }
}
```

This works fine for an `Int` range, which is what you specified in your question. From the Apple documentation:

> You can create a countable range over any type that conforms to the
>   Strideable protocol and uses an integer as its associated Stride type.
>   By default, Swift’s integer and pointer types are usable as the bounds
>   of a countable range.

Comment: That's what Martin pointed out in the linked answer. I wanted to avoid duplication of the `subscript`.

Comment: Actually, what Martin pointed out was that you could define separate methods for `Range` and `ClosedRange`. The problem with doing that is that you would have to duplicate all of the code in those methods. The benefit of instead using the Countable versions is that you can convert one to the other, thereby avoiding the duplication. Notice I only have the logic inside one of the `subscript` methods.

Comment: But actually you are using duplication of `subscript` with `Countable[Closed]Range` and that's what I want to avoid :-/ I want this `subscript` only once for both range-kinds. This Swift is a brain-wreck.