# Return an array of Integers within a range

Tags: arrays, swift, random, swift3

I am very new to Swift and would like to create a function that returns an array of random integers, all within a specified range. This is what I've come up with but it doesn't feel very "Swifty" to me. Would someone proficient with Swift take a different approach?

```
func randomNumber(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
  let min = range.lowerBound
  let max = range.upperBound
  return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(1 + max - min))) + min
}

func randomNumbers(range: ClosedRange<Int>, count: Int) -> [Int] {
  var array = [Int]()

  for _ in 0..<count {
    let n = randomNumber(range: range)
    array.append(n)
  }

  return array
}

let nums = randomNumbers(range: 10...20, count: 5)
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371326/swift3-random-extension-method for some methods to create a random value in a range.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34712601/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `randomNumber()` is <strike>expensive</strike> not efficient because `min` and `max` are extracted in each call (aka in each iteration of the loop)

This might be a bit *swiftier*

```
func randomNumbers(range: ClosedRange<Int>, count: Int) -> [Int] {
    let min = range.lowerBound
    let randomMax = UInt32(1 + range.upperBound - min)
    return (0..<count).map {_ in return Int(arc4random_uniform(randomMax)) + min }
}

let nums = randomNumbers(range: 10...20, count: 5)
```

Comment: Wow - that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: ClosedRange is just a struct. It would be interesting to know if accessing lower/upperBound is really "expensive".

Comment: @MartinR I changed the phrase.